# click to open image and click to close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of thumbnails and when clicking on any of it, it enlarges.

I could achieve this: open an image (enlarged) and then clicking again to return it to its normal size. Then I clicked again but it is not enlarging. Why is is this happening and how can I solve this?

```js
$("#thumbs img").click(function() {
 $(this).addClass("enlarge");
 $("#thumbs img").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("enlarge");
 });
});
```

```css
#thumbs {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 300px;
}

#thumbs > img {
   cursor: pointer;
   float: left;
   margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.enlarge {
   transform:scale(3,3);
   transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbs">        
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
   <img class="thumbnail" src='http://www.mariajuliaolivan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/random-1000x600.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">           
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a click event in a click event?  Consider using toggleClass.

```
$("#thumbs img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("enlarge");
});
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy like that!